# How to specify the endoint of a REST API accepting a list of types using a supertype?

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest, request

I intend to specify a REST endpoint in a Spring Boot application which accepts a list of objects (`List<? extends SuperObject>`). `SuperObject` is an abstract base class. The lists sent within the RequestBody of an HttpRequest keeps instances of `SuperObject`'s sub-/childclasses (`SubType1OfSuperObject` and `SubType2OfSuperObject`).

Currently I tried this:

```
@PostMapping(path = "store", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public String store(@RequestBody List<? extends SuperObject> oject, @RequestParam Technology technology) {
    theService.saveObjectsByTechnology(objects, technology);
    return "Perfect!";
}
```

I tried to send a list of subtype objects using *Postman*:

```
{
  "subtype1OfSuperObjects": [
    {
      "prop1": 4,
      "prop2": "foo",
      "prop3": "xxx"
    },
    {
      "prop1": 7,
      "prop2": "Bar",
      "prop3": "zzz"
    }
  ]
}
```

The result is

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-08-18T12:24:55.797+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "path": "/admin/error/store"
}
```

The SuperObject class:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@Validated
public abstract class SuperObject  {

    private Integer prop1;

    private String prop2;

}
```

The SubType1OfSuperObject class:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@Validated
public class SubType1OfSuperObject extends SuperObject  {

    private String prop3;

}
```

The SubType1OfSuperObject class:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@Validated
public class SubType2OfSuperObject extends SuperObject  {

    private String prop4;

}
```

How can I achieve this. The classes of the `supertype` and the `subtypes` are implemented, of course.

The REST API is accessible as I can invoke another (GET) endpoint (to list all subtypes, for instance).

Comment: In the words of Fielding, REST has no endpoints but only resources. Next, a server should teach a client on what to send if a server expects some input through form-like representations, i.e. HTML supports forms that define where to send the request to, what operation to use, the media type the representation is generated for and the respective elements a server expects as input. Anything other isn't REST but pure RPC. JSON featureset does not include such capabilities, however, in JSON Schema you could use `{ ..., "type": { "$ref": "supertype"}, ...}` to define such a relation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it well you have a list of data to send? if that's the case you can have something like below:

In your controller

```
@PostMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public String save(@RequestBody List<Data> data){
    System.out.println(data);
    return "good";
}
```

And you define your Data pojo like this

```
class Data{
    private List<SubData> subtype1OfSuperObjects;
    //getters, setters and toString
}

class SubData{
    private int prop1;
    private String prop2;
    // getters, setters and toString
}
```

Here is the result of by sysout

```
[Data{subtype1OfSuperObjects=[SubData{prop1=4, prop2='foo'}, SubData{prop1=7, prop2='Bar'}]}]
```